# prove the function $w=\sqrt{z}$ is continuous for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, formal-proofs

I search a lot for the answear and many topics here about this questions says the function is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. But the book doesn't says anything about this interval. It requests to prove for all set of complex. Well, what I know is for any point $z$ and $z_0 \neq 0$ we have

$|f(z) - f(z_0)| = |\sqrt{z}- \sqrt{z_0}|= | \frac{z-z_0}{\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{z_0}} | < \epsilon$.

Now what should I do to prove this using $\sqrt{z} = r^{\frac{1}{2}}e^\frac{i\theta}{2}$ and $\sqrt{z_0} = r_0^{\frac{1}{2}}e^\frac{i\theta_0}{2}$ ?

The book says to consider the fact $|\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{z_0}|^2= r + r_0 + 2\sqrt{rr_0}cos(\frac{\theta + \theta_0}{2}) > r_0 $

Answer (score 1):

It isn't continuous on all of $\Bbb C$.  You need a *branch of the square root function*, and the largest subset you can define it on is $\Bbb C$ minus a *slit*, like $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: And how can I prove that?

Comment: Well, it's a little complicated.  If you try to define it on all of $\Bbb C$, you actually get a multi-valued function, because of the fact that trigonometric functions are periodic and the square root is defined in terms of them, via $z^{1/2}= e^{\ln{z^{1/2}}}$ and Euler's formula.

Comment: Great.  I think you're on the right track.  Maybe something like:  $|\dfrac{z-z_0}{\sqrt z+\sqrt {z_0}}\lt|\dfrac{z-z_0}{\sqrt{r_0}}|\lt\epsilon $ if $\delta\lt\epsilon\sqrt{ r_0}$.